# Can someone explain how this programs gives this output?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

```
int x = -2139062144;  //In binary: 10000000100000001000000010000000
int k = x << 1;
```

`k` is `16843008` (binary: `1000000010000000100000000`), and I don't understand why?

How did `10000000100000001000000010000000` change into `1000000010000000100000000` by just one left bit shift?

I expected it to be: `10000001000000010000000100000000` conserving the sign as in right bit shift sign is conserved.

Comment: What don't you understand? What result did you expect?

Comment: I expected it to be: 10000001000000010000000100000000 as sign has to be conserved, right? In case of right bit shift sign is always conserved!

Comment: A note on formatting: Either use hex or at least use some digit separators.  Counting '0's is error-prone.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple.

Your `int` can carry only a maximum of 32 bits. Well, exactly 32 bits, all the time.

In

```
 10000000100000001000000010000000
```

the most significant, leading bit, is 1.

What do you think happens to this doomed bit, as a result of a left shift?

It's gone. It ceased to exist. It joined the choir invisible. It's an ex-bit.

And, of course, there is a freshly-born, 0 bit in the least significant position. So you end up with

```
00000001000000010000000100000000
```

as a result, or:

```
1000000010000000100000000
```

Comment: Why isn't the sign conserved? In right shift we have sign conserved, right?

Comment: See the link given in the other answer. You've observed the most common way C++ implementations implement the left shift operator.

Answer (score 7):

Left shift of a negative value has undefined behaviour. Anything may happen, including what you see.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators